# Take JSON from YQL and process it with Google Books API

Tags: json, api, yql

I'm using YQL to query a Google Spreadsheet for a list of ISBN's. I'd like to take those ISBN's and use Google Books API to generate a column of Google Preview buttons for those books.

Here's a fiddle I've started:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpuXG

Now in this example from Google, ISBNs are submitted as a form and that input is used by the Google API / JSON.

http://goo.gl/b15yC

Is there a way to get Google's API to take the ISBNs from the existing JSON object from my YQL instead of the input form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to do something similar is via Google Books bookshelves (not with a spreadsheet or YQL). Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TECHg/1/